# While sorting users by their distance to the logged in user, how can those users with distances > 5miles be excluded from display?

Tags: swift

I am sorting from closest to the logged in user currently. I just want to exclude those outside 5 miles from the display.

Currently I am doing

```
let distance = locCoord.distance(from: self.dict)



self.homosapians.sort { ($0.distance ?? 0) < ($1.distance ?? 0) }
print("cake", self.homosapians.map {$0.distance})
self.table.reloadData()
}



public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {let person: Userx = homosapians[indexPath.row]
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
let like = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UIButton
let immy = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
cell.lblName.text = person.Education
cell.postID = homosapians[indexPath.row].postID
if let PhotoPosts = person.PhotoPosts {
let url = URL(string: PhotoPosts)
immy.sd_setImage(with: url)
}
 return cell
}
```

Summary. What I have: Sorting via distance from logged in user.
What I need: To exclude those outside 5 miles.

Comment: You may as well point out that [this was cross-posted to reddit.](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/d1xy2w/i_am_currently_sorting_other_users_based_on/)

Answer (score 1):

```
self.homosapians.filter {  
  guard let distance = $0.distance else { return false }
  return distance <= 5
}.sorted { $0.distance! < $1.distance! }
```

Comment: The `?? 0` is semantically incorrect. At that point, you know you'll have no `nil` distances, by virtue of the line above. If that branch *is* ever used, it indicates a logical error, and should be surfaced with a crash, rather than silently failing. It's better to force unwrap it.

Comment: @SchrgCat Thanks. where would that filter looks go in context of the code I already have? I assumed it would replace self.homosapians.sort. I got Result of call to 'sorted(by:)' is unused

Comment: No problem, you should use that snippet to get items for tableView. So I would say that probably you should create filteredHomosapians and then in methods for tableView use that instead of homosapians. You can also put it into custom setter of homosapians, if you don't need these objects that will be throwed out by filter.

Comment: @SchrgCat Thanks. I get Result of call to 'filter' is unused. Since you are Returning, why would it say this? Upstream I also have this:  public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        
        return homosapiens.count
     
    }

Comment: That's because filter and sorted return new sequence, not modifying the sequence that they were called on. You have to use assignment to save the result somewhere. As I wrote before I suggest creating separate variable if you'll need the whole collection of homosapiens or modify the homosapiens itself, if you can throw some elements out. If your use case it's the latter, then `homosapiens = self.homosapiens.filter {` will work

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the many question. I'm not very experienced yet. How would you use assignments in this case? Would you put this block of code, and then elsewhere call: let "filter I guess" = .....?

Comment: @SchrgCat and as to whole collection vs throw out. The ones outside 5 miles are thrown out upon display of the table view, but once the come within 5 miles, they are included.